# Unit in the image of a cp map

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

This is another question which looks non-trivial to me. Suppose that we have a completely positive map $f\colon M_n \to M_m$ such that $f(a) = I_m$, the identity matrix on $M_m$. Is there a positive element $b\in M_n$ such that $f(b)=I_m$?

Comment: What is a completely positive map $f:M_n \to M_m$?  What are its defining characteristics?

Comment: It is a pretty standard notion. A linear map $f\colon A\to B$ (here $A,B$ are C*-algebras) is *completely positive* if for each $n$, the map $f\otimes I_n$ is positive (here $I_n$ is the identity matrix on $M_n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, in general.

Let $n=m=2$. Define, for $x\in M_2(\mathbb C)$, 
$$
f(x)=x_{11}\,\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+x_{22}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This map is linear. It is also positive, because if $x\geq0$ then $x_{11},x_{22}\geq0$ and the two matrices are positive. And it is completely positive, because its range lies within an abelian subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb C)$ (the diagonal algebra).

We have
$$
f\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right)=I_2.
$$
And no positive matrix  is sent to the identity: if $f(x)=I_2$, then necessarily
$$
2x_{11}+x_{22}=1,\ \ x_{11}=1.
$$
So the only solution is $x_{11}=1$, $x_{22}=-1$.